# Splash screen image. How To add this in my app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I would like to add a splash screen image in my app. what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: copy and then paste...simple!

Comment: There's heaps of [Q&A's already dealing with this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+splash+screen) - have you looked at those before asking yet another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/tutorials/Creating_a_Splash_Screen

here is a simple tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Set an activity as main. In its XML layout add an `ImageView`. Set an image for that `ImageView`. Create a thread to run this activity for a specific amount of time. Once that time is over, call an intent to the next activity.